# Is it halal to eat meat given the mistreatment of farmed animals?

Tags: halal-haram, food, business, animals, meat

As a Muslim the Quran taught me peace and compassion. I can understand if meat was made halal. Although I don't think it was made as a requirement. So if we can eat cruelty free, why wouldn't we?

Even if meat is Halal:

1. farming animals is causing a toll on the environment
2. The grains fed to make one piece of steak can cure world hunger
3. farmers are using steroids and hormones and antibiotics this enters into our bodies.
4. animal cruelty also exists in Halal slaughter houses
5. chickens are being exploited for human consumption but hens are getting over worked to produce eggs as there is no male to fertilize her eggs
6. cows and other halal animals are being falsely inseminated to breed meat for eating, and to produce milk.

These animals do not live a natural happy life. How can this be halal?

Comment: I think in most muslim countries people have no choice and meat isn't something all people could have for their meal. And most people who could buy local food will get meat from more or less "happy" animals. As the farming industry produces mostly for export! Therefore it would be hard to find a clear source without much interpretation saying this. And Allah knows best

Comment: Yes but we shouldn't contribute and support it. we cannot turn a blind eye and pretend that we are not supporting the torture of animals. Allah knows best but we cannot fool our selves and Allah is all knowing so we must respect his creations.

Comment: Meat that's allowed to eat isn't entirely based on how it's slaughtered, but also it being pure I.e. tayyib.  The issue of chemicals involved would probably fail the purity(tayyib) test and may not be halaal.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the problem mentioned above are modern ones. ie(Steroids,Hormones,industry).

Some general well known principal fiqh of Halal/Haram meat is that the source must be known as to know if it was slaughtered properly, that it is not Pork (or what is known to be haram), dead meat (taken from an animal while alive).

> He has only forbidden to you dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah . But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its limit], there is no sin upon him. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. Quran (2:173)

---

> “Whatever is cut from an animal hen it is still alive, what is cut from it is Maitah (dead meat).”  Grade  : Hasan (Darussalam), Book 28, Hadith 3337

---

It is well known that mankind can live without meat (vegan), since meat in most cases ancient case was known as a luxury (to this day in some places it could be).

To solve most of the issue (farming industry) try getting your meat from a local farmer (if possible) and look for yourself to the condition of the animals. If we all did this really there would be no need for such a industry to exist.

You can mention meat all day but even if you go the vegan way you must be careful since there is also a major fitna in the agro industry which is GMO (Genetically Modified Organism), which some country banned for potential health issue.

So to make it short it is not that something halal is being bad today due to the industry but rather our approach towards these very halal things are causes for concern.

> For each one are successive [angels] before and behind him who protect him by the decree of Allah . Indeed, Allah will not change the condition of a people until they change what is in themselves. And when Allah intends for a people ill, there is no repelling it. And there is not for them besides Him any patron. Quran(13,11)

So my short answer would be to support your local farmers.

*I hope it answers the question.*

Comment: I am vegan and try to stay away from GMO as much as possible. but I am concerned about the larger muslim community regarding diet and the food industry.

Comment: In that case bringing it to a scholar would be best